# Datatables show details multiple rows returns undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am trying to show multiple rows of child row in datatables. I am unable to figure out why it is returning undefined when I view the data. I even tried moving the function before the init the datatable but that didn't really change the result. This is an MVC (asp) project and the html shown below is test data but in reality I am pulling the data from sql server. Below is my code:

JS

```
var table = $('#E1, #E2, #E3').DataTable({
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns('.select-filter').every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value="">Show 
All</option></select>')
                        .appendTo(column.header())
                        .on('change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });
                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    var val = $('<div/>').html(d).text();
                    select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
                });

            });

        },
        sort: false,
        scrollX: true,
        fixedColumns: {
            leftColumns: 2,
            heightMatch: 'auto'
        },
        fixedHeader: {
            headerOffset: 50
        },
        buttons: [
            'excel'
        ],
        deferRender: true,
        deferLoading: true,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
    });

    $('#E1, #E2, #E3').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format({
                'Key 1': tr.data('key-1'),
                'Key 2': tr.data('key-2'),
                'Key 3': tr.data('key-3'),
                'Key 4': tr.data('key-4'),
                'Key 5': tr.data('key-5')
            })).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
    function format(data) {
        var html = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:600px;">';
        for (var key in data) {
            console.log(data[key]);
            html += '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + key + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[key] + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
        }
        return html += '</table>';
    }
```

HTML

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item 1</th>
        <th>Item 2</th>
        <th>Item 3</th>
        <th>Item 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-key-1="Value 1" data-key-2="Value 2" data-key-3="Value 3" data-key-4="Value 4" data-key-5="Value 5">
        <td class="details-control">data 1a</td>
        <td class="details-control">data 1b</td>
        <td class="details-control">data 1c</td>
        <td class="details-control">data 1d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-key-1="Value 1" data-key-2="Value 2" data-key-3="Value 3" data-key-4="Value 4" data-key-5="Value 5">
      <td class="details-control">data 2a</td>
        <td class="details-control">data 2b</td>
        <td class="details-control">data 2c</td>
        <td class="details-control">data 2d</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it as follows:

HTML

```
    <tr data-child-value1="data1" data-child-value2="data2" data-child-value3="data3">
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
 $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } else {
                    // Open this row

                    row.child(format(tr.data('child-value1'), tr.data('child-value2'), tr.data('child-value3'))).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            });
            function format(value1,value2,value3) {
                var html = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">';

                    html += '<tr>' +
                        '<td> D1</td>' +
                        '<td>' + value1+ '</td>' +
                        '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
                        '<td> D2</td>' +
                        '<td>' + value2+ '</td>' +
                        '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
                        '<td> D3 </td>' +
                        '<td>' + value3+ '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';

                return html += '</table>';
            }
```